# AJAX values converted to PHP Variables?

Tags: functions, jquery, ajax

I just started playing with Wordpress and I have a question about the AJAX side of things.

I think that I understand how the AJAX front-end to server side processing, back to font-end works.

But, I am not that clear on how I could get front-end data into the back-end and then use that data for something else (not returning a value to the front-end). I have been reading allot of different posts and it is something that is never fully fleshed out.

Ideally, I would take the front-end data and convert it into a PHP variable that could be called in a different PHP function or functions (not done in function.php but in a custom plug-in PHP file).

Is this possible? If yes, I am curious on how I would go about it.

If not, what would be the best way of getting front-end data into the back-end for manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You would save the Ajax response to the database.

Here are a few tutorials that might be helpful:

- [Tutorial on Using Ajax in Wordpress Plugins](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/)
- [How to Use Ajax for Data Insertion in WordPress](http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-for-data-insertion/)
- [How to Insert Data into Database using Ajax](http://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: if you wanted to do a type ahead search box (rendering results) using jQuery and ajax would that be possible? You would be writing to the db everythime you captured a character on the front end-then querying for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary, you echo the value on the traitement page, and in your ajax request, you get put the echo in a variable, like :

```
resultats = ajax.responseText;
```

Comment: Please do not use this site to spam. I have removed the link. You will get banned for spamming, so please do not spam.